# Recursively convert all folder and file names to lower-case or upper-case

Tags: ruby

I have a folder structure like follows. 

`-FOO
  -BAG
     Rose.TXT
-BAR
    JaCk.txt`

I need the following output.

`-foo
  -bag
    rose.txt
-bar
    jack.txt`

Comment: do you need the file names like "/foo/bag/rose.txt" or do you need a datastructure?

Comment: No, i need just convert the folder and files to lower-case or upper-case only. I don't need to return any type of structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realize you want ruby code, but I present to you a one liner to run in your shell:

```
for i in `find * -depth`; do (mv $i `echo $i|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`); done
```

as found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=244738

Run it once, and it should do the trick.

### Update

**Ruby Code:**

```
Dir.glob("./**/*").each do |file|
  File.rename(file, file.downcase) #or upcase if you want to convert to uppercase
end
```

Comment: thanks @Mike. I already know the shell script. But, i need the code in ruby. thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. `system("for i in `find * -depth`; do (mv $i `echo $i|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`); done")`

Comment: :) @Rein, Yeah i know the trick work also. Is it possible to through RUby?. Please let me know the ruby code. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir["**/*"].each {|f| File.rename(f, f.downcase)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work: when it tries to convert a directory first and then a file in that directory.

Here is the code that does work:

```
Dir.glob("./**/*").sort{|x| x.size}.each do |name|
  x = name.split('/')
  newname = (x[0..-2] + [x[-1].downcase]).join('/')
  File.rename(name, newname) 
end
```

(it sorts the list by length, so the direcotry will be converted after the file in it)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive directory listing :

http://www.mustap.com/rubyzone_post_162_recursive-directory-listing

Uppercase/lowercase conversion :

http://www.programmingforums.org/thread5455.html

Enjoy :)

Comment: thanks @SpyrosP. This is not correct answer for my question. Please read my question again.

Comment: Why not ? You want a directory listing and a way to convert upper -> lower and viceversa. The 2 resources describe how to do both. Combining them is a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of [Find.find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/find/rdoc/classes/Find.html) is all you need:

```
require 'find'
Find.find(directory) do |path|
    if(path != '.' && path != '..')
        File.rename(path, path.downcase)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename your files recursively, you can use `**/*`

```
folder = "/home/prince"
Dir["#{folder}/**/*"].each {|file| File.rename(file, file.downcase)}
```

If you just want the file array output in lowercase

```
Dir["#{folder}/**/*"].map(&:downcase)
```